# Create flow chart in HTML5

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I want to create the flow chart using the HTML5 with Grid Layout

Detailed info:
- Must be able to drag 5 elements to the sheet (event, condition, action, data, end)
- Elements can connect to eachother (drag line from element to element)
- Condition element has a true / false connector
- Elements must snap to grid
- Must be possible to resize elements and give them a name
- Should work like MS Visio (easy to learn)

Can i get the step by step procedure like above mentioned.

Present i am able to drag the objects.

Now the next step is i want to connect the two objects

which it is similar to the diagramo layout.

How to show the connectors of each object when i hover it?

Answer (score 1):

To connect two objects by dragging line from one object to other object try this..

```
var X,Y,temp=0;//Global Varaibles

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown',function(evt){

X = evt.clientX;
Y = evt.clientY;
temp = 1;
},false);

canvas.addeventListener('mouseup',function(evt){
temp=0;
},false);

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',function(evt){
if(temp == 1)
{
context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
//re draw all the objects
context.beginPath();
context.strokeStyle = '#000000';
context.moveTo(X,Y);
context.lineTo(evt.clientX,evt.clientY);
context.stroke();
context.closePath();
}
},false);
```

See demo in fiddle : [Jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MrL7p/)

Answer (score 0):

The way you let your users drag the 5 elements onto your panel/canvas, so the same way you should let your users drag a connector to the panel/canvas.

The obvious choice being, one vertical connector and one horizontal connector, that totals up to 7 elements in all. 5 with your basic objects and 2 for your connectors.

You may also need a means of allowing your user to set the connector height for vertical connectors.

And a means for setting the width of horizontal connectors.

If that goes well then you could add diagonal connectors too, 
from north-west to south-east and north-east to south-west if you choose to do so.

Comment: can i have the example of joining the objects?

Comment: Post your code that you have already for dragging your 5 objects and I will try and add it to that.